# Python: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, pip

I have a installation problem with pip where I failed to install a library called `minecraft`

```
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_zussc0h\\minecraft\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_zussc0h\\minecraft\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_zussc0h\minecraft\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_zussc0h\minecraft\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(NOTICE, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_zussc0h\\minecraft\\setup.py\\..\\..\\NOTICE.rst'
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I try some methods to fix it, like "pip install -U setuptools", but is it not working.

So, i really don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?

By the way, i am using Python3

Comment: @Heisenberg Uh, no. My library is https://pypi.org/project/minecraft/ . Also i know, that is not for linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/minecraft/

> **This is not a usable Python package**, but the name is reserved by Micro$oft Corporation.

(Emphasize and edits are mine — *phd*)

This is a bug in the package, not sure if it's deliberate. The package is uninstallable but anyway it's not intended for installation.